# PixiJS: Affine projection vs bilinear one

Tags: projection, pixi.js, affinetransform, quad

Let's say there is an arbitrary composite shape in PixiJS:

[image]

I need to project a texture onto it by some kind of a grid warp in a way, so the result would be:

[image]

I have tried to do it via PIXI.SimplePlane and it seems that default projection algorithm at this framework is affine transformation. And the result have to be based on quad bi-linear projection.

Yes, PixiJS has additional projections plugin (https://pixijs.io/examples/#/plugin-projection/quad-homo.js), but it seems that output could be controlled just by four corner points. In my case, I need more. At least 10 or even 15.

If I couldn't use projection plugin, maybe there is a way to implement a custom shader?!

```js
let pattern64 = "data:image/png;base64,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";


 const app = new PIXI.Application({ width: 512, height: 324, antialias: true });
    document.body.appendChild(app.view);

    app.loader.add('pattern', pattern64).load(inits);

    function inits() {

        const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

        let path = [34, 100, 176, 100, 176, 224, 34, 224];

        graphics.lineStyle(0);
        graphics.beginFill(0xBCBCBC, 1);
        graphics.drawPolygon(path);
        graphics.endFill();

        path = [176, 100, 258, 60, 258, 264, 176, 224];

        graphics.lineStyle(0);
        graphics.beginFill(0xCDCDCD, 1);
        graphics.drawPolygon(path);
        graphics.endFill();

        path = [258, 60, 422, 104, 422, 220, 256, 264];

        graphics.lineStyle(0);
        graphics.beginFill(0x606060, 1);
        graphics.drawPolygon(path);
        graphics.endFill();

        path = [422, 104, 478, 104, 478, 220, 422, 220];

        graphics.lineStyle(0);
        graphics.beginFill(0x909090, 1);
        graphics.drawPolygon(path);
        graphics.endFill();

        app.stage.addChild(graphics);

        const texture = app.loader.resources.pattern.texture;

        const plane = new PIXI.SimplePlane(texture, 5, 3);
        app.stage.addChild(plane);

        let buffer = plane.geometry.getBuffer('aVertexPosition');

        // graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        // graphics.drawRect(buffer.data[20], buffer.data[21], 8, 8);
        // graphics.endFill();

        //manually set just for this demo
        buffer.data[0] = 34;
        buffer.data[1] = 100;
        buffer.data[2] = 176;
        buffer.data[3] = 100;
        buffer.data[4] = 258;
        buffer.data[5] = 60;
        buffer.data[6] = 422;
        buffer.data[7] = 104;
        buffer.data[8] = 478;
        buffer.data[9] = 104;

        buffer.data[10] = 34;
        buffer.data[11] = 162;
        buffer.data[12] = 176;
        buffer.data[13] = 162;
        buffer.data[14] = 258;
        buffer.data[15] = 162;
        buffer.data[16] = 422;
        buffer.data[17] = 162;
        buffer.data[18] = 478;
        buffer.data[19] = 162;

        buffer.data[20] = 34;
        buffer.data[21] = 224;
        buffer.data[22] = 176;
        buffer.data[23] = 224;
        buffer.data[24] = 258;
        buffer.data[25] = 264;
        buffer.data[26] = 422;
        buffer.data[27] = 220;
        buffer.data[28] = 478;
        buffer.data[29] = 220;

        buffer.update();

    }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/6.5.5/browser/pixi.js"></script>
```